# Use Java8 map over Optional.Empty()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I have a piece of code where am doing something like:

```java
Optional<College> college = Optional.ofNullable(student)
        .map(stud ->  stud.getCollege())
        .get()
        .stream()
        .filter(college -> Objects.nonNull(college.getCollegeName()))
        .findFirst();
```

Now, while writing an unit test, I got a catch that what if student comes as `null`?

It would be effectively like:

```java
Optional.empty()                         // the same as the student is null
        .map(stud -> stud.getCollege())
        .get()
        .stream()
        .filter(college -> Objects.nonNull(college.getCollegeName()))
        .findFirst();
```

Which I think is not fine because I am getting Exception

```
expected<com.src.exceptions.CollegeNotFoundException> but
was<java.util.NoSuchElementException>
```

#Update

Updating the question details for clarifications

1. Yes stud.getCollege() returns a list<>

Comment: Is `student` a `List`? And does `getCollage()` return a `List`?

Comment: Provide code of your college and student classes.

Comment: `Optional` is not meant to be used like the way you are intending to use, use it only for return types. For internal calls use `!= null` or `Objects::requireNotNull`. You will often find people abusing `Optional` very much, it's like using `Map` when you can get something done with `List`

Comment: @tdranv updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Nikolas approach except that you should not return `null`, returning `null` at last is against using `Optional`
What about this one:

```
Optional<College> optional = Optional.ofNullable(student)
                .map(stud -> stud.getCollegeList())
                .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
                .stream()
                .filter(c -> Objects.nonNull(c.getCollegeName()))
                .findFirst();
```

Comment: Returning `null` after a chain of `Optional` methods is nothing bad. It depends what is needed. You cannot say what is better without knowledge of the context.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `Optional::get` with no previous check `Optional::isPresent` is dangerous because it might produce `CollegeNotFoundException`. And it is not the way the `Optional` shall be used. The idea of `Optional` is mapping/filtering the values and providing a *default* value if the `Optional` ends up with no element (empty).

Assuming `Student::getCollege` returns `List<College>` having method `College::getCollegeName`, you can do the following:

```
College college = Optional.ofNullable(student)
    .map(stud -> stud.getCollege())
     // if Optional is empty, then use an empty collection
    .orElse(Collections.emptyList())                              
    .stream()
    .filter(c -> Objects.nonNull(c.getCollegeName())) 
    .findFirst()
     // get the value or else college is null 
    .orElse(null);
```

As long as `stud.getCollege()` returns `null`, the `Optional` becomes empty and an empty list will be streamed. And again the same principle is applied: As long as the list is empty, the `filter` and `findFirst` are not be called and `null` is safely returned (or any default value you wish).

Also note that the line `.filter(c -> Objects.nonNull(c.getCollegeName()))` might also produce `NullPointerException` as long as there is not guaranteed `stud.getCollege()` doesn't return a list with a `null` element (remember the list is not `null` itself so `Optional` treats it as a "valuable" item). The safe code actually looks like:

```
Optional<College> college = Optional.ofNullable(student)
    .map(stud -> stud.getCollege())
    .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
    .stream()
    .filter(c -> c != null && c.getCollegeName() != null)
    .findFirst();
```

Actually, I prefer to return either a null-object, `null` or `Optional` itself.

Comment: Hi @Nikolas Appreciate your effort for explaning, but basically the output am expecting is kind of Optional<College>

Comment: @Nikolas Please remove the last line so that I can delete my answer

Comment: I've elaborated about the return value.

Comment: @Nikolas the updated code still gives me exception of the same type.

Comment: I have a doubt that .map(stud -> stud.getCollege()) would actually return NoSuchElementException ? as their no value present when Optional.ofNullable(student) returns empty()

Comment: I had a mistake. `.map(stud -> stud.getCollege())` itself doesn't throw such exception, but the `.get()` does. Check my edit.